# How to get record between two date and month not year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

> I have following records

```
NAME       BIRTHDATE 
 A         19/09/1990
 B         25/09/1992
 C         26/09/1993
```

and current date is 19/09/2014
I want to get the birthday record from current date to next seven days below is my query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Birthday]
as
begin
Declare @CurrentDate date ,@NxtDate date

set @CurrentDate = GETDATE(); 
set @NxtDate = DATEADD(day,7,getdate())
print @CurrentDate
print @NxtDate
select DocId, DoctorName,DOA,Email from vw_DoctorDetail 
where DOA between @CurrentDate and @NxtDate
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Birthday]
as
beginDeclare @CurrentDate date ,@NxtDate date

set @CurrentDate = DATEADD(year,-DATEDIFF(year,'19000101',GETDATE()),GETDATE()); 
set @NxtDate = DATEADD(day,7,@CurrentDate)
print @CurrentDate
print @NxtDate
select DocId, DoctorName,DOA,Email from vw_DoctorDetail 
WHERE DATEADD(year,-DATEDIFF(year,'19000101',DOA),DOA) between @CurrentDate and @NxtDate
```

Comment: You are having some calculating issues around leap year. It is really minor, but if today is 2016-02-28, you will only be checking for dates from 02-28 until 03-07. The right number would be 03-06. I am almost sure the QA can live with that

Comment: Nice catch though. It really depends on how the OP would like to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT DocId
    ,DoctorName
    ,DOA
    ,Email
FROM vw_DoctorDetail
WHERE (
        DATEPART(DAY, DOA) BETWEEN DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE() + 7)
            AND DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())
        )
    AND DATEPART(MONTH, DOA) = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())
```

Comment: What if today is one of the dates of the last week of the month? The seventh day from now won't have the same month as today.

Answer (score 2):

This will work from sqlserver 2012+
Notice this is using 2000 which is leap year to avoid issues.

```
SELECT 
  DocId, 
  DoctorName,
  DOA,
  Email 
FROM 
  vw_DoctorDetail 
WHERE 
 datefromparts(2000, month(DOA), day(DOA)) 
   between datefromparts(2000, month(@CurrentDate), day(@CurrentDate)) and 
              datefromparts(2000, month(@NxtDate), day(@NxtDate))
```

Comment: This wouldnt work in a non leapyear. if you use Year(@currentdate) instead of 2000 it correctly calculates it whether its a leapyear or not.

Comment: @pancho018 actually it works fine, and I don't care if it is leap year or not since it doesn't affect my calculation